# Hide ad banner with in app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing, ads, banner

How do i remove the banner ads and text view after the user has made purchase with in app billing. After the user made a payment, the banner and text does go away but as soon as they terminate the app and open again, the banner and textview still shows up but the difference is when they tap the textview, the toast *"Thanks for your purchase"* shows and the text and banner disappear then. How can i make them to not appear at all upon oncreate. thanks

[image]

**MAIN**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{
BillingProcessor bp;
AdView Adview;
TextView textView6;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "YOUR LICENSE KEY FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE", this);
    MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    Adview=findViewById(R.id.adView);
    textView6=findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()/*.addTestDevice("")*/.build();
    Adview.loadAd(adRequest);

}
public void onClickAds(View view){
    bp.purchase(MainActivity.this, "android.test.purchased");
}

@Override
public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Thank you for your purchase",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ViewGroup parent1 = (ViewGroup) Adview.getParent();
    ViewGroup parent2 = (ViewGroup) textView6.getParent();
    parent1.removeView(Adview);
    parent2.removeView(textView6);
    parent1.invalidate();
    parent2.invalidate();
    }

@Override
public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

}

@Override
public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "AN ERROR OCCURED.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onBillingInitialized() {

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (bp != null) {
        bp.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

**XML**

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.42"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickAds"
    android:text="Don't like seeing ads? Tap Here!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using shared preference for this issue

following step will help you

step 1. Initialize at top

```
private static final String PREF_FILE  = "PREF_FILE";
private static final String IS_PRODUCT_PURCHASE = "IS_PRODUCT_PURCHASE";
```

step 2. inside onProductPurchased() method add these line

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean(IS_PRODUCT_PURCHASE,true);
    editor.commit();
```

setp 3.call this method inside onCreate() at last

```
private void checkForIsPurchase() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isPurchase = preferences.getBoolean(IS_PRODUCT_PURCHASE, false);
    if (isPurchase) {
        Adview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textView6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problems are always well come.